# Can I copy output from sage to my clipboard?

Tags: python, clipboard, sage-math

I run [sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) from the terminal. One nice feature of sage is that it can automatically latex-ify results. I would like to be able to pipe these results to my clipboard (I run Ubuntu 14.04). I have naively tried

```
sage: A = matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
sage: latex(A)
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{array}\right)
sage: latex(A) | xclip -sel clip
  File "<ipython-input-25-10899c791764>", line 1
    latex(A) | xclip -sel clip
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: If it's Sage, perhaps you could use Python based tricks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7606100/2072269